# How can i auto-login with Fedora 15? So that it never ask it on reboot automatically logs in, as defined

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, centos, gdm

In the earlier versions of Fedora there was a way to use `gdmsetup` for auto-login. Now in Fedora 15 I can't auto-login anymore. Anyone know how I can do this?

I cannot figure out how to stop it from showing a login prompt.  I have tried:

```
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=user1
```

It still shows the user1/password login prompt and wait for few seconds and then auto login. But I want it to log in right away and go straight to the desktop.

Comment: TimedLogin will also work, add an additional directive (`TimedLoginDelay=0`) to go straight to the desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying the daemon section of `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=USERNAME_HERE
```

If you set `AutomaticLogin=root`, gdm will refuse to automatically log you in for security reasons. Use a regular user account instead.

Comment: Excellent. It works exactly how i was trying to make it. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome :)